# Hex to NSString with scaling 0x40 bytes

Tags: nsstring, char, hex, byte

Second day trying to get the character from byte value which was scaled by 0x40 bytes

I'm trying to get hex value from Logic Pro/Mackie Control.

Logic sends me 0xE, it mean this is 'n'. If it sends me '4e' it mean I should draw on the display 'n.' (simply add dot at the end).

Here is formula for converting char to byte. Please help me made vice versa formula.

```
char translate_seven_segment( char achar )
{
    achar = toupper( achar );
    if ( achar >= 0x40 && achar <= 0x60 )
        return achar - 0x40;
    else if ( achar >= 0x21 && achar <= 0x3f )
        return achar;
    else
        return 0x00;
}

char s = 'N';
    Byte ad = translate_seven_segment( s ) + ( '.' == '.' ? 0x40 : 0x00 );
```

I found also following code (this seems without topper()):

```
def translate_seven_segment( char )                      
    case char                                       
      when 0x40..0x60                                   
        char - 0x40                                     
      when 0x21..0x3f                                    
        char                                         
      else                                        
        0x00                                         
    end                                        
  end
```

How I can reverse it ? I know mackie use this code to build hex from char. But I need vise versa, is to get char from hex.

Comment: You got a bunch of things wrong there.  You shouldn't do `toUpper` if the incoming value is not a UTF8 char -- it simply garbles the data.  You should mask off the `40` bit (AND with 0xBF) and then ADD 0x40 to get your base character (after which you can do toUpper if you wish).  AND the original character with 0x40 to test for the `.` indication.

Comment: It is not I'm doing this. This is original Mackie code. I need only to convert dex to char. I know Mackie seems use this formula.

Comment: Some place you gotta find the specs.  It seems to me what you have is maybe the code to convert ASCII to 7-segment, not the other way around.  And this makes no sense `( '.' == '.' ? 0x40 : 0x00 )` -- it will always evaluate to 0x40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I see you added the note about wanting to reverse the sequence.  If that's the case it's fairly simple:

```
BOOL haveDot = (the7Segment & 0x40) != 0;
char temp = the7Segment & 0xBF;
char theChar = (temp > 0x21) ? temp : (temp + 0x40);
```